# Divide and conquer problem:sequence of integers (with possible repetitions)

Tags: algorithms, divide-and-conquer

I was trying to solve this problem.

Let $A[1] . . . , A[n]$ an ordered sequence of integers (with possible repetitions) and let $k$ be any integer. A contiguous subsequence $A[i], A[i + 1], . . . A[j]$ of $A$ is $k$-separated if the difference between every pair of its consecutive elements is at most $k$.

For example, if $A = [1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8]$, then the contiguous subsequence $3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5$ is $1$-separated but not $0$-separated.

We would like an algorithm that given $A$ and $k$ as input returns the length of the longest contiguous k-separated subsequence.

Some examples:

- Input: $A = [1, 3, 3, \textbf{4, 4, 4}, 5, 7, 8]$, $k = 0$. Output: $3$ (longest contiguous $0$-separated subsequence has been hightligthed)
- Input: $A = [1, \textbf{3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5}, 7, 8]$, $k = 1$. Output: $6$ (longest contiguous $1$-separated subsequence has been hightligthed)

This can be solved in $O(n^2)$ with a nested loop that checks all possible contiguous subsequences but we would like to do
better.

I understand that I need to split my array in 2, but after that I don't know how to find the condition to select first half or second.
How will be the algorithm to find the correct answer? Any help it's welcome.

Comment: Please don't delete your question after receiving a question.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers, that will be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a divide-and-conquer algorithm, you can cut the array $A = [a_1, …, a_n]$ in two arrays by the middle $B = [a_1, …, a_{\frac{n}{2}}]$ and $C = [a_{\frac{n}{2}+1}, …, a_n]$.

Then the longest $k$-separated sequence in $A$ is one of the three following:

- the longest $k$-separated sequence in $B$;
- the longest $k$-separated sequence in $C$;
- the concatenation of the longest $k$-separated sequence in $B$ ending with $a_{\frac{n}{2}}$ with the longest $k$-separated sequence in $C$ beginning with $a_{\frac{n}{2}+1}$, with the condition $a_{\frac{n}{2}+1} - a_{\frac{n}{2}} \leq k$.

Now the first two values can be computed recursively, and the third can be computed easily in time complexity $O(n)$. The complexity of this algorithm verifies $C(n) = 2C\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + O(n)$, which implies $C(n) = O(n\log n)$.

Without divide-and-conquer, I think there exists a $O(n)$ dynamic programming algorithm:

For $A = [a_1, …, a_n]$ and $i \in [\![1, n]\!]$, define:

- $f(i)$: length of the longest $k$-separated sequence in $[a_1, …, a_i]$;
- $g(i)$: length of the longest $k$-separated sequence in $[a_1, …, a_i]$ ending with $a_i$.

Then it is easy to see that:

- $g(i + 1) = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}1 & \text{if }a_{i+1}-a_i >k\\ 1 + g(i)&\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$
- $f(i + 1) = \max(f(i), g(i + 1))$

That way, you can easily compute $f(n)$, which is the value you want, in time complexity $O(n)$.

Comment: Please write a complete question, I cannot understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I wrote the algorithm in english, you need to figure out the details by yourself, otherwise you will not make any progress.

Comment: I'm sure you can find it yourself!